# Does SP in db2 waits for triggers to execute

Tags: multithreading, stored-procedures, jdbc, triggers, db2

We have scenario where we want user to update certain tables in DB2. Which we are doing using a SP and transaction management is done for same. However, now we need to introdue one new table for logging user actions, but we don't want to keep user waiting for same. Can we write trigger in this scenrio.

If I call SP from outside someother language like java, when the this SP is updating the row, a trigger will called on that row. 
In such scneario  , is SP going to wait for trigger to complete execution or will return just by completing udpate execution of row and trigger will run in separate thread.

I tried to implement same , not sure how to be confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DB2 does not have asynchronous triggers.  Triggers are compiled as part of the SQL statement being executed that will necessitate their use.  You can see this by explaining a query.